# No files changed but Git Eclipse project explorer indicates there are

Tags: eclipse, git, svn, version-control

Eclipse indicates I have files changed under my project root folder, but clearly there aren't any. To help you see the issue I've attached a screen shot below

[image]

See that `>` mark next to my project root folder? That indicates I have changed files, but none of the sub-folders have that mark. This is important because now it does not let me switch to another branch unless the changes are committed.

Here's the steps to reproduce my problem (at least how it happened on my machine):

1. I was originally in my local branch which is a clone of remote **origin/develop** branch.
2. I created a new **feature branch** and checked it out.
3. Worked on some features, then **committed** the changes to **origin/develop** branch.
4. **Switched back** to my local develop branch (where I was at in the beginning). Only to find out that the files I've changed in the **feature branch** are all marked as changed by the `>` mark, but if I look into the files they are identical to the remote origin/develop branch that I cloned off before - NOT CHANGED.
5. Now it does not allow me to checkout other branches unless I commit these "changed files". So I did a hard reset on it, but still the marks are there and eclipse won't let me switch branch.
6. I got mad, did a **pull** from origin/develop. Then finally all `>` marks are gone **except** for the one pointing to my project root folder.
7. If I **switch** to the **feature branch** I worked on again and then switch **back** to local develop, everything goes back to **step 4**.

Is this an Eclipse related issue? Or is there something I did wrong? Please help, I'm lost!

Comment: Try disabling any filters that are active in the view from its local menu.

Comment: What's the output of `git status`?

Comment: It was due to an unstaged file. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can see from your image there is one untracked file in your project thats why you are getting `>`  sign on root of your project.

To clean it:

1. Open Git Repository View in eclipse.
2. Right Click select **clean**
3. Select all the files and choose **Finish**

[image]